# Download an image using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, imagedownload

I need to find an image in a HTML code similar to this one:

```
...
<a href="/example/11/1"> 
    <img src="http://example.net/example.jpg" alt="Example"/>
</a>
...
```

and download the image in src.

Comment: 1) Invalid html, 2) [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), 3) look at [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be a good starting point for you:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://yahoo.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
counter = 0
for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    with open("image" + str(counter),'wb') as f:
        f.write(urllib2.urlopen(img['src']).read())
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**This will help locate source of the image file.**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

word = 'pizza'

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'

url = "https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=ciling+fan&qs=n&form=QBILPG&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=ciling+fan&sc=8-4&sk=&cvid=73D78D239D574921A293EF9725CD2F65"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 

request=Request(url,None,headers) #The assembled request
response =urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
counter = 0

for ul in soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'dgControl_list '}):
    for li in soup.find_all('li'):
        for images in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'img_cont hoff'}):
            s = images.find('img')
            img = s.get('data-src')
            if img != None:
                with open("Z:\pyimages\image" + str(counter) +".jpeg",'wb') as f:
                    f.write(urlopen(img).read())
                    counter += 1
```

Comment: **it will give you source of all the images available on that page.**